# Dynamic Query Re-write or Evaluating the Query Before Executing Table Function

Tags: oracle

First, I want to make it clear that the question is not about the materialized views feature.

Suppose, I have a table function that returns a pre-defined set of columns.

When a function call is submitted as

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM TABLE(my_tfn(:p1))
WHERE col4 = 'X';
```

I can evaluate the parameter and choose what queries to execute.
I can either open one of the pre-defined cursors, or I can assemble my query dynamically.

What if instead of evaluating the parameter I want to evaluate the text of the requesting query?

For example, if my function returns 20 columns but the query is only requesting 4,
I can assign NULLs to remaining 16 clumns of the return type, and execute fewer joins.
Or I can push the filter down to my dynamic query.

Is there a way to make this happen?
More generally, is there a way to look at the requesting query before exuting the function?

Comment: I would hate to have to support that sort of thing.  If the query is in a stored procedure, you could potentially inspect the call stack and use the data dictionary to look up the query from your code.  You might be able to get the sql_id for the current session and look up the query text but I wouldn't assume that would work across versions.  I would think that it would make much more sense to let the function accept an additional parameter if you want to change the behavior.

Comment: If you are really determined, you could use advanced rewrite to have an arbitrary query actually execute a completely different query https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_advanced_rewrite I would be very judicious about doing that sort of thing, however, because it makes debugging the system rather "interesting".

Comment: Thank you Justin. This is very useful. The only problem is that it seems I have to know in advance what the requesting query will be. Hoping for some way to look at the text of that query. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no robust way to identify the SQL that called a PL/SQL object.

Below is a not-so-robust way to identify the calling SQL.  I've used code like this before, but only in special circumstances where I knew that the PL/SQL would never run concurrently.

This *seems* like it should be so simple.  The data dictionary tracks all sessions and running SQL.  You can find the current session with `sys_context('userenv', 'sid')`, match that to `GV$SESSION`, and then get either `SQL_ID` and `PREV_SQL_ID`.  But neither of those contain the calling SQL.  There's even a `CURRENT_SQL` in `SYS_CONTEXT`, but it's only for fine-grained auditing.

Instead, the calling SQL must be found by a string search.  Using a unique name for the PL/SQL object will help filter out unrelated statements.  To prevent re-running for old statements, the SQL must be individually purged from the shared pool as soon as it is found.  This could lead to race conditions so this approach will only work if it's never called concurrently.

```
--Create simple test type for function.
create or replace type clob_table is table of clob;

--Table function that returns the SQL that called it.
--This requires elevated privileges to run.
--To simplify the code, run this as SYS:
--  "grant execute on sys.dbms_shared_pool to your_user;"
--(If you don't want to do that, convert this to invoker's rights and use dynamic SQL.)
create or replace function my_tfn return clob_table is
    v_my_type clob_table;
    type string_table is table of varchar2(4000);
    v_addresses string_table;
    v_hash_values string_table;

begin
    --Get calling SQL based on the SQL text.
    select sql_fulltext, address, hash_value
    bulk collect into v_my_type, v_addresses, v_hash_values
    from gv$sql
    --Make sure there is something unique in the query.
    where sql_fulltext like '%my_tfn%'
        --But don't include this query!
        --(Normally creating a quine is a challenge, but in V$SQL it's more of
        -- a challenge to avoid quines.) 
        and sql_fulltext not like '%quine%';

    --Flush the SQL statements immediately, so they won't show up in next run.
    for i in 1 .. v_addresses.count loop
        sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge(v_addresses(i)||', '||v_hash_values(i), 'C');
    end loop;

    --Return the SQL statement(s).
    return v_my_type;
end;
/
```

Now queries like these will return themselves, demonstrating that the PL/SQL code was reading the SQL that called it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_tfn) where 1=1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_tfn) where 2=2;
```

But even if you go through all this trouble - what are you going to do with the results?  Parsing SQL is insanely difficult unless you can ensure that everyone always follows strict syntax rules.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.

Comment: What am I going to do with it? I am researching different techniques I can employ to have a single TFN that can satisfy many different requests.
Suppose, the return type is a flattened data set that joins together many related tables. But when only a handful of attributes is requested, I want to avoid unnecessary work.
Not sure whether I can use your technique. Concurrency is one issue. But this something for me to think about. This is for the data virtualization solution I am designing.